# How to show a div when a particular button is clicked,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This my js code:

- i want to click first button to call a new class,it works but, every
  button doing same work. when i click second button this also calling
  a new class.please help me to solve this.

  ```
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){      /*button click event*/
      $(".new").toggle();                /*new class calling */
      });
    });
  </script>
  ```

  this my html code:

  ```
  <button>first</button><br>  
  <button>second</button><br> 
  <button>third</button><br>

  <div class="new" style = "display: none;">hi.</div>  <!--i need to call only this class-->
  <div class="old"><a href="www.google.com">hello.</a></div>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give id's to the buttons, n call those accordingly like

```
$("#first").click(function(){      
     $(".new").toggle();              
});
```

Comment: i have multiple buttons and click functions in a page,when i click this first button (above) and the trigger event occurs..this works but when i click other buttons that calls trigger event ...please help me how to solve this...

Comment: you need to give different id's to different buttons

Comment: <button id="first">first</button><br>  
<button  id="second">second</button><br> 
<button  id="third">third</button><br>

Answer (score 1):

You have to set an id to that particular button and then attach click event handler to that particular button using id. Here is the code.

```
<button id ='myBtn' >first</button><br> 

 $("#myBtn").click(function(){      /*button click event*/
$(".new").toggle();                /*new class calling */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contains('first')`.

The thing is that your using `button` as selector, that will not understand which button is clicked actually.

I would recommend, To make jQuery understand you should provide any specific id to that element.

But if you want to do it based on the text inside a DIV, you can use `contains('first')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button:contains('first')").click(function(){      /*button click event*/
      $(".new").toggle();                /*new class calling */
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>first</button><br>  
<button>second</button><br> 
<button>third</button><br>

<div class="new" style = "display: none;">hi.</div>  <!--i need to call only this class-->
<div class="old"><a href="www.google.com">hello.</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").eq(0).click(function() { /*button click event*/
    $(".new").toggle(); /*new class calling */
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>first</button>
<br>
<button>second</button>
<br>
<button>third</button>
<br>

<div class="new" style="display: none;">hi.</div>
<!--i need to call only this class-->
<div class="old"><a href="www.google.com">hello.</a>
</div>
```

use `.eq()` to select which button you need the click

Note: eq() is index based which starts with 0

Answer (score 1):

If you want to click first button to call a new class , you can do by many ways .Here is checking with clicked text to get first button click

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){      /*button click event*/
    if ($(this).text() == "first" )  $(".new").toggle();                /*new class calling */
    });
  });
</script>
```

set `id` is the better

```
<button id="first">first</button><br>  
<button>second</button><br> 
<button>third</button><br>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").click(function(){      /*specific button click event*/
        $(".new").toggle();                /*new class calling */
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `$("Button")` you are referring to the Button element and not a certain Button so every button will do the same action. You should give your Buttons an id and then call them based on their Id.

Like:

```
<button id="firstBtn">first</button><br>  
<button id="secondBtn">second</button><br> 
<button id="thirdbtn">third</button><br>
```

And then call them with the id selector `#` like so: `$("#firstBtn").click()..`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline style and use a separate css class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() { /*button click event*/
    $(".new").toggleClass('hide'); /*new class calling */
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/akvr3z7k/)

Comment: if i have a multiple click function and multiple buttons in a page ,then how can i call a particular button function